# Use Excel VBA to update column cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

This is a simple answer but one I cannot find.

I have two columns of data.

Column A (1) has yes/no data validation list options in every cell.

Column B also has data validation with say 6 strings of text options in every cell.

But I only want each the corresponding cell (column B) to update in the same row as column A

e.g A20 toggled, then B20 is updated. Like so

A20 is selected “Yes” from the dropdown option and B20 is updated with the string “complete” which is one of the states you can select in the dropdown boxes manually in every cell in column B.

I had some code but I would have to write an argument for every cell and then two macros for every yes / no.

This is code that works for one cell only but this is not ideal for many cells but it works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A20")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("A20")
            Case "Yes": Macro_001
            Case "No": Macro_002
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub

Sub Macro_001()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("August 2020").Select
    Sheets("August 2020").Range("B20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Complete"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub

Sub Macro_002()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("August 2020").Select
    Sheets("August 2020").Range("B20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

There much be an easier way with .range perhaps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer tab click view code, choose the sheet you want the macro to run on, make sure the upper left drop down says worksheet and the upper right says Change (I'll assume your sheet has headers):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim ChangeCell As Range
Dim numrows As Long

numrows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set TriggerCells = Range("A1")
Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B" & numrows)

If Application.Intersect(TriggerCells, Range("A1")) = "[Column Header Text]" Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = "Completed"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Try that, see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi thanks, I did try it but it didn’t seem to work. 

It’s assigned Worksheet (UL) & Change (UR). 

My sheet is a standard default excel sheet that’s only just been converted to a macro sheet

So a couple things that are different from the original code. 

The trigger column is E & the Key cells are in Column G. 

Row 2 is where the first trigger cell appears Row 1 is off limits. 

Updating things to E & G didn’t seem to get a response out of it.
In the code where you have “[Column Header Text]” should that be “E” - the column is not named apart from the default excel lettering.

Comment: Did you enter the column header name (row 1) into the "[column header text]"?  If not and you don't want to make sure that this only applies to that column, then remove the first If statement.